# How to download files from TFS server using Jenkins slave running on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, team-foundation-server

My Jenkins slave running on a Linux machine and I need to download packages from TFS servers, I have installed TFS plugin in Jenkins and provided all the details , should that be sufficient to use tf get commands in execute shell or do I need to install tf utility on my Linux servers? Please let me know if there is any other way as well to get the artifacts from TFS in my Linux based Jenkins Slave.

Thanks in advance!

Regards, 
Piyush

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, as of v 4.0.0, the plugin itself embeds the SDK and thus no longer requires the CLC.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md

We have been running linux nodes accessing tfvc and git repositories in TFS using Jenkins 1 and Jenkins 2 against TFS 2103 - TFS 2018.

Comment: Actually we were running TFS 2010 so plugin support is not very good, that is the reason we are using TLCC explicitly as plugin doesnt takes care of special characters like "space" and "-" in the collection url.

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue fixed using the process below:

- Installed TF Team Explorer EveryWhere Utility on my Jenkins master
- Downloaded the package using `tf get` on the Jenkins master
- Then transferred it to the Jenkins slave machine.